# How would be method to write this into a If success or if submit else

Tags: jquery, if-statement

Here is my validation code that goes with the form, it works as is.

But I would like to add another function to it, as it success or there are not validation errors and ready for form submit to perform another function during

I just want to combine the two into one statement, that when form is success or return true, do loading wait.

```
            if (ValidationErrors[FormID].join("|").search(id) == -1) 
            ValidationErrors[FormID].push(id);
            return false;

           }else {

           for (var i = 0; i < ValidationErrors[FormID].length; i++) {

            if (ValidationErrors[FormID][i] == id) 

            ValidationErrors[FormID].splice(i, 1);
           }

             return true;
         }
      }

           Loading function


        function ShowProgressAnimation() {
              $("#loading-div-background").css({ opacity: 0.8 });
               $("#loading-div-background").show();
               $(".button-2").hide();
        }
```

FIRST TRIED THIS VERSION:

```
              if (ValidationErrors[FormID].join("|").search(id) == -1) 
              ValidationErrors[FormID].push(id);
             return false;

            }   else {
            for (var i = 0; i < ValidationErrors[FormID].length; i++) {
                if (ValidationErrors[FormID][i] == id) 
                    ValidationErrors[FormID].splice(i, 1);

            } else {


                 function ShowProgressAnimation() {
               $("#loading-div-background").css({ opacity: 0.8 });
               $("#loading-div-background").show();
               $(".button-2").hide();

          }         

            return true;
        }
```

SECOND VERSION:

```
         if (ValidationErrors[FormID].join("|").search(id) == -1) 
          ValidationErrors[FormID].push(id);
            return false;
        }
        else {
            for (var i = 0; i < ValidationErrors[FormID].length; i++) {
                if (ValidationErrors[FormID][i] == id) 
                    ValidationErrors[FormID].splice(i, 1);
            } 



           function() {

                               $(ShowProgressAnimation() {
               $("#loading-div-background").css({ opacity: 0.8 });
               $("#loading-div-background").show();
               $(".button-2").hide();

                   });
             }            

            return true;
          }
```

THIRD VERSION:

```
           if (ValidationErrors[FormID].join("|").search(id) == -1) 
            ValidationErrors[FormID].push(id);
            return false;
        }
        else {
            for (var i = 0; i < ValidationErrors[FormID].length; i++) {
                if (ValidationErrors[FormID][i] == id) 
                    ValidationErrors[FormID].splice(i, 1);
            } 

                              function ShowProgressAnimation() {
               $("#loading-div-background").css({ opacity: 0.8 });
               $("#loading-div-background").show();


                return true;
              }
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Where exactly are you stuck here?

Comment: I have tried several things. None worked. All need to do is get the function ShowProgressAnimation()  to be added with submit() per each form after validations takes place.

Comment: "I have tried several things". What are they? Please post them. Please explain where you are stuck with them.

Comment: Tried these serveral formats here and none seem to work:

Comment: See the version I have tried and none seem to work as needed: See above

Comment: With all of these versions, I don't see where you are calling your function.

Comment: Okay, how would I do that to get the function to operate on submit()